# Ubuntu/Mac Setup — Show Samba and Netatalk

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, samba, file-sharing, netatalk

I have setup Netatalk at my home for Time Machine backups, and I would also like for my samba shares to show up on my MacBook.
Here is what I currently see:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2n9ltg471k1k30u/Screenshot%202014-10-29%2007.17.47.png?dl=0

When I disable Netatalk on my Ubuntu server, my samba shares show up after about 3-4 minutes.

Is there a way to get both to show?

I'm running Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you disable netatalk/avahi, netbios on your OS X machine discovers the server. When OS X detects two servers with the same name on both Bonjour and Netbios it will prefer the Bonjour discovered one over the Netbios one.

You can advertise both of the services via Bonjour/Avahi, however when both SMB and AFP shares are advertised only AFP will show. To overcome this you can use a different hostname for AFP and SMB.

For example, my `/etc/avahi/services/smbd.service` file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" standalone='no'?>
 <!DOCTYPE service-group SYSTEM "avahi-service.dtd">
 <service-group>
      <name replace-wildcards="yes">%h - Samba</name>
      <service>
           <type>_smb._tcp</type>
           <port>445</port>
      </service>
 </service-group>
```

And my `/etc/avahi/services/afpd.service` file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" standalone='no'?>
 <!DOCTYPE service-group SYSTEM "avahi-service.dtd">
 <service-group>
      <name replace-wildcards="yes">%h</name>
      <service>
           <type>_afpovertcp._tcp</type>
           <port>548</port>
      </service>
 </service-group>
```

This shows up in Finder as:

[image: Example in Finder]

Comment: Hey, this somewhat works. But the shares aren't showing up (only for samba!), but the samba thing is there. Did you change the port for samba? If so, what was the original.

Comment: Scrap that, they're showing now!